# Subsequential limits of partial sums of rearranged conditionally convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

First some background: I was trying to prove that given a conditionally convergent series of reals and an arbitrary subset $S$ of $\mathbf R$, the series can be rearranged so that the set of subsequential limits of partial sums is exactly the closure $ \bar S $ of $S$. The case of a finite $S$ being standard, the way I thought one could proceed for an infinite $S$ was this: get a countable dense subset $\{x_n:n\ge 1\}$ of $S$.

Now, define a subsequence as follows: $n_1 := 1, n_2 := \min \{ n > n_1: x_n > x_{n_1} \}, n_3 := \min \{ n > n_2: x_n < x_{n_2} \}, $ and so on; 
i.e. for all $k \ge 1$, 
$$ n_{2k} = \min \{ n> n_{2k-1} : x_n > x_{n_{2k-1}} \}, \quad n_{2k+1} = \min \{ n > n_{2k} : x_n < x_{n_{2k}} \}\mbox . $$ 
If at any stage $ x_{n_{2k-1}} = \max(S) $ or $ x_{n_{2k}} = \min(S) $, then define the next term arbitrarily from the subsequent terms of the sequence. 
The proof could now be completed if it is true that the subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\ge 1}$ is also dense in $S$ (the idea as in the standard proof of Riemann's Theorem is to add just enough positive terms from the series to exceed $x_{n_{2k}}$, then just enough negative terms to fall below $x_{n_{2k+1}}$, successively for every $k\ge 1$). But is it, or is there a counterexample?

Incidentally, my hunch is that the outlined proof of the original problem will still work if it can only be shown that $(x_{n_k})_{k\ge 1}$ doesterm in the subsequence arbitrarily, not remain bounded away either from $ \sup(S) $ or $\inf(S)$ (treated respectively as $\infty$ and $-\infty$ if $S$ is respectively unbounded above and below), but this question seems of independent interest.